# Jquery to Bring in Mysql data to Div (other options)

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

What I have is a list of client names which when I click them I want some mysql data to load in the div next to their names and so on,

I know already I can do this with an AJAX request by binding an onlclick function to divs that their names are stored in and then using that to trigger the Ajax request to get the data and then append it to the DIV on the page.

I'm wondering if there's any other way to do the same thing which is light weight and fast and efficient?

Comment: Is your AJAX implementation not light weight/fast/efficient?

Comment: it is, im just wanting to know if there are any other wats of doing this

Answer (score 0):

You have either:

1. AJAX
2. iframe
3. Load whole page

Those are really your only choices.